# Best structure / rewrite rules to achieve the following url

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, rewrite-rules, customization

I have been trying to achieve the following url structure in Wordpress and maintain a level of reusability in the admin area.

It is for a client preview area and needs to reflect multiple versions of different file types.

So the desired URL structure would be:

http://preview.mysite.com/client-name/wireframes/v1/homepage/

/client-name/ is a dashboard view showing links to /wireframes/ as well as /mockups/ or anything else that is a design phase.

/v1/ relates to the version number of /homepage/

The easiest way is to use pages and sub pages but there must be a better way. More of a CMS way. Maybe there isn't. Perhaps Wordpress is the wrong choice for this.

Comment: hmmm its not clear exactly what you want each 'part' to represent. Is client-name a username or a taxonomy or a post type? Do you mean v1 of the homepage wireframe?

Comment: I don't know which is the best approach.
/client-name/ is a 'dashboard' view of everything - so wireframes, mockups, concepts, prototypes.
/wireframes/ would list all wireframes associated with that /client-name/

and yes, /v1/ relates to the version of /homepage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling is that you want to use custom taxonomies for part of this. So client-name would be one taxonomy (flat), version would be another taxonomy (also flat). Wireframes might a post type or a taxonomy, not sure what makes sense for you. A little googling led me to the following links, that you might be able to shake and bake into something useful.

I agree that pages and sub-pages would be a cumbersome way to achieve this, since you'd need to recreate the tree structure for every client. With custom taxonomies, you'd create the structures once and re-use them.

- [How can I rewrite URLs to pass taxonomy and post type values to the query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7827/how-can-i-rewrite-urls-to-pass-taxonomy-and-post-type-values-to-the-query/7873#7873)
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/
- http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/
- http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: Looks promising. My main concern was showing the custom taxonomies in the url structure so they appear hierarchical.

Comment: Also with this approach, I will potentially have a custom post type of 'Wireframes' and within that, dozens of posts with the same name 'Homepage' which I'm sure wordpress won't allow (would have to have different slugs) and there will be no easy way to identify them. I think I may need to rethink using wordpress for this.

Comment: I see what you mean. There might be a way to make use of WP's internal versioning system, but figuring that out is way above my pay scale.

Comment: Hmm... maybe my question doesn't really have an answer then. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: Just ran across this: http://ben.balter.com/2011/08/29/wp-document-revisions-document-management-version-control-wordpress/